# knockout component registration does not execute viewModel and could not append template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-components

For a simple test.html, knockout component works fine in my simple test.html, I mean it executes the view model and appends template successfully but doesn't work in a huge index.html. Anyone have an idea?

file test.html:

```
  <html>   
    <body> 
    <div id="mandiv" class data-bind="component: 'user' "> </div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='./js/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script> 
  </body>  
  </html>
```

file app.js:

```
var userModel = function() {
         console.log("I inside model");
        firstname = ko.observable("aaa");
        lastname = ko.observable("bb");
        console.log("firstname: " + firstname());
        console.log("test");
        this.fullname = ko.pureComputed(function(){

            return firstname() + " "  + lastname();   
        }); 

};

console.log("I out here");

ko.components.register('user', {
    viewModel: userModel,
    template : '<p> <input type="text" placeholder="first name" data-bind="value:firstname"> </p> ' +    ' <p> <input type="text" placeholder="last name" data-bind="value:lastname"> </p>' + '<p> full name :  <span data-bind="text: fullname"> </span> </p> </div>'


});

ko.applyBindings();
```

It works fine on test.html.
In a huger index.html, I did the same thing. But it does not work. It did not execute the viewModel and could not append the template. Due to my index.html is too long, I just copy the related code.

index.html related code:

```
 <div id="mandiv" class="hidden" data-bind="component: 'user' "> 
 </div>
```

Before this div and after this div are separate divs. And include knockout.js and app.js before any js file. It does not work. Any ideas? Appreciated!

Comment: Try removing the 'var' before userModel.

Answer (score 0):

For one, I would start using var self = this; then append all properties to self in your viewModel.

```
userModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.firstname = ko.observable("aaa");
    self.lastname = ko.observable("bb");
    self.fullname = ko.pureComputed(function(){
        return self.firstname() + " "  + self.lastname();   
    });

    return self;
};
```

second, create a new instance of the viewModel instead of using the same instance multiple times?

```
ko.components.register('user', {
  viewModel: {
    createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) { 
      return new userModel();
    }
  },
  template : '<p> <input type="text" placeholder="first name" data-bind="value:firstname"> </p> ' +    ' <p> <input type="text" placeholder="last name" data-bind="value:lastname"> </p>' + '<p> full name :  <span data-bind="text: fullname"> </span> </p> </div>'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried your version but it still only works in test.html and does not works in index.html. I somehow made it work once a time, but now could not remember.

Comment: I suspect you might have another problem in your index.html that's causing this to fail, in my experience it is not uncommon for knockout not to say anything when it can't find some deep leveled binding, but then visually break on the next part.

Comment: I figured out  the "working" case is I have a parent div and another model (original model) applied regular binding to this div, then I have a child div and it applies binding to the USER model through component (registering + binding). In that case, the user model template get loaded successfully.  But if I removing binding for the parent div, it does not work. If I remove the child div and bind the user model to the parent div  through component , it doe not work either.

Comment: I have some script code in index.html about the parent div, but it is only about removing or adding class "hidden".  My goal is to separate index.html since it is a little huge.